# Haskell commandline argument handling library

Tags: haskell, command-line-arguments

I've been using [cmdargs](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs) for argument processing for a while, and it's great.  However, I don't see a facility for long option names with a single hyphen, e.g. `-option1 -option2` or the more difficult `-optx` which is equivalent to `--opt=x`.  I need to maintain compatibility with an existing application, so these formats are both necessary.

System.Console.Getopt doesn't seem up to it either.  Can anyone either provide a sample of how to do this with cmdargs, or suggest an alternative library which will support this?

Comment: GNU convention is two dashes for long options. I think, libraries like getopt are designed with the purpose to enforce this convention consistently. If I were you I'd try to use getArgs directly and write my own non-standard option processing function (ImageMagick style or whatever).

Comment: @jetxee - I could do that, but then I have to write my own help messages.  At least it would be relatively simple to parse getArgs for this.  Oddly enough, it's a gnu executable I need compatibility with.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the simplest thing you can do is to do a quick pre-processing pass yourself. For example, if you need to support exactly the three options `-option1`, `-option2`, and `-optx`, Something like this should work:

```
munge "-option1" = "--option1"
munge "-option2" = "--option2"
munge s | "-opt" `isPrefixOf` s = "--opt=" ++ drop 4 s
munge s = s

main = do
    realArgs <- getArgs
    withArgs (map munge realArgs) mainThatUsesCmdArgs
```

As you say, though, the help messages would then no longer mention the possibility of having these short forms. (Perhaps that's a good thing, though.)

If you want more, you will probably have to convince somebody to modify cmdargs.